# Reading a specific column from a text file in C#

Tags: c#, file-io

I am trying to read from from a text file (notepad) that looks like this:

```
Hours: 10 Date: 09-4-2014  
Hours: 2 Date: 03-4-2014  
Hours: 17 Date: 04-4-2014  
Hours: 6 Date: 06-4-2014
```

And I want to save the sum of all the hours inside an int:

```
int SumOfHours = 10 + 2 + 17 + 6
```

How can I do this?

Comment: for starters can you show a clearer example of what the file layout looks like.. also what are the delims of that file are you familiar with the split() function

Comment: you could do something like this and the hours in regards to the array position should be in the same location and write your own += place holder from there 
`var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\YourFile.txt").Select(a => a.Split(' ')).ToArray(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given much details on the format of the file. Just to get you started, you can try something like(using System.Text.RegularExpressions):

```
File.ReadLines("path").Sum(
    line 
        => 
    int.Parse(Regex.Match(line, @"Hours:\s(\d+)").Groups[1].Value))
```